# How to save an array?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

How to save an array? If I receive and send data in this form?

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {order_name: "sd", cost: 12, quantity: 1}
1: {order_name: "sd", cost: 12, quantity: 1}
2: {order_name: "sd", cost: 12, quantity: 1}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

When I try to save, I get such an error:

> a null value in the order_name column violates the NOT NULL constraint

controller:

```
module.exports.create = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const order = await Order.bulkCreate([{
            order_name: req.body.order_name,
            quantity: req.body.quantity,
            cost: req.body.cost,
            date: new Date(),
            users_id: req.decoded.user_id
        }]);
        res.status(201).json(order);
    } catch (e) {
        errorHandler(res, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `req.body` is an array of objects and not just objects, so you need to use the `req.body` directly in the `bulkCreate` function as the property also matches directly with the model property. Currently, you are trying to access `req.body.order_name` which will be undefined since `req.body` is an array. To fix the code, you need to do this:

```
module.exports.create = async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const order = await Order.bulkCreate(req.body);
    res.status(201).json(order);
  } catch (e) {
    errorHandler(res, e);
  }
}
```

Just make sure that you validate your payload and property values according to your requirement before you bulk create the documents.

If you want to add some other properties from the backend code then:

```
module.exports.create = async function(req, res) {
  let createArray = req.body.map((obj) => {
    obj.date = new Date(),
    obj.user_id: req.decoded.user_id
  });
  try {
    const order = await Order.bulkCreate(createArray);
    res.status(201).json(order);
  } catch (e) {
    errorHandler(res, e);
  }
}
```